# Possible problem with ComponentOne controls in vb6

Tags: vb6

I am using the following custom controls in legacy vb6 applications. These applications have been know to crash on exit - if run from inside the development environment the applications will crash the development environment - has any one seen where these controls might have caused that problem, and what I might do to correct it? thanks
ComponentOne Sizer/Tab Controls 8.0
ComponentOne Spell 8.0 control
ComponentOne VSFlexgrid 8.0 (OLEDB)

Comment: I'm looking at a project right now that uses C1Awk 8.0, Sizer/Tab 8.0, VSFlexGrid 8.0 (OLEDB and Light), VSPrinter 8.0, and VSReport 8.0, and have never had any problems with it crashing the IDE.  Are you sure the problem is related to the C1 controls?

Comment: NO I'm not totally sure, I've been over hooks and subclasses and just everything I could think of - now I am working on the custom controls

Comment: If you've got hooks and subclassing going on, I'd definitely check and double check all that code before starting in on the C1 stuff. Hooks of any sort have to be done +exactly+ right or you'll get all kinds of strange crashes in the Vb6IDE. I've used many of the C1 controls in projects and never had issues like that either...

Comment: Wild guess, but are you using XP control styles through a manifest & API calls? because that can cause your app to crash on exit. http://www.vbaccelerator.com/home/vb/code/libraries/xp_visual_styles/Preventing_Crashes_at_Shutdown/article.asp

Comment: +1 To offset the unfair downvotes and closevotes on your [perfectly good follow up question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6363659/vb-6-crash-on-exit). You're practically being bullied over there.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried using the [latest builds](http://prerelease.componentone.com/)? I recently had a problem getting a .NET winform designer to show with a VsFlexGrid8 .ocx on it. The problem was something to do with ATL and Windows 7 security, IIRC. Switching to a later (stable) build solved my problem.

Answer (score 0):

Somethings that happens when you have addins. Enter in your vb6 Turn off addins closed again open vb6 execute your application if is successfull enable addins.